# Organize Bash Menu using Case

Tags: bash, case-statement

When I add multiple options to the case to choose from; I want the list to not appear only in an endless vertical list, but also make it go horizontal. Would gladly like the help :) 
 [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9cFK.png)

Comment: Replace image with its text.

Comment: Take a look at `help select`.

Comment: `select` is the command for menus. Simlest example: `select x in {1..100}; do break; done; echo $x`